# How to add a child selector and child element to a variable, referencing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a child selector and child element to a variable, referencing an element.
but i can't seem to get it working..
I've tried;

```
  var wrapper = $('#wrapper');

  if($(wrapper+' > .box').length > 0)) // unsuccessful

  if(wrapper.add(' > .box').length > 0)) // unsuccessful

  and

  if(wrapper[0]+' > .box'.length > 0)) // unsuccessful
```

thanks cam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're confusing the selection with the selector. If you were to have done:

```
var selector = "#wrapper";
var wrapper = $(selector);
```

Then you could test it appropriately:

```
if ( $(selector + " > .box").length )
```

Note that `>` is the [first-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild) selector.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing .box is a direct child of wrapper, and you're trying to check if it exists, so you could probably do:

```
var wrapper = $('#wrapper');

if ( wrapper.children('.box').length ) {
    //wrapper has direct child .box
}
```